# Import symfony images, don' t have access to httpd.conf - Symfony 1.4

Tags: php, symfony1

When i want import this from Symfony library on local server  I usually do this:

```
//in server httpd.conf
Alias /symfony/web/sf /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/symfony/lib/vendor/symfony/data/web/sf
<Directory "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/symfony/lib/vendor/symfony/data/web/sf">
    AllowOverride All
    Allow from All
</Directory>
```

But now i have my project on external server and I just don' t have access to httpd.conf. How I can import this elements to my project ? Now I can' t see any images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not an expert of .htaccess, but I am some what certain that this can be done using rules. also... I did a search to help you out and I found.
[symfony documentation Alias](http://www.symfony-project.org/cookbook/1_0/en/web_server) scroll down to alias. Also make sure you check the log file if you do endup running into problems.

Comment: Thanks, this is it! I just can make a rule that will redirect to symfony/data/web/sf. :)